# How to use pdfcomment within a caption?

Tags: floats, captions, pdfcomment

I would like to leave comments in a PDF file, for which purpose the `pdfcomment` package seems to be a useful option. However, when I tried to use `\pdfmarkupcomment` within a caption, my comment has not been displayed in the PDF file (at least, I could not find anywhere within the file). Could you please help me how to reach the desired effect within a caption? My MWE is as follows:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{pdfcomment}

\begin{document}

\pdfmarkupcomment[markup=Highlight]{Text}{Stupid comment.}

\begin{figure}
    \caption{\pdfmarkupcomment[markup=Highlight]{Caption}
    {Another stupid comment, which is not displayed in the PDF file.}}
    \label{fig:lab}
\end{figure}

Fig.~\ref{fig:lab} is a blank figure.

\end{document}
```

Comment: it doesn't work in floats. Imho due to a bug in the soulpos package: https://github.com/jbezos/soulpos/issues/1

Comment: @UlrikeFischer It's a pity, but thanks. It would be good to have a workaround for this problem.